# Matplotlib Area Under Curve conditional color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to fill the area between two line plots as such:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


ROCE = np.array([-7.0,-14.0,-11.0,8.0,7.0,17.0,10.0,9.0])
WACC = np.array([4.5, 5.1, 4.7, 3.4, 2.9, 3.7, 3.6, 3.9])
YEAR = np.array([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(YEAR, ROCE, color = 'blue')
ax.plot(YEAR, WACC, color = 'black')
ax.fill_between(YEAR, ROCE, WACC, where=ROCE >= WACC, facecolor='green')
ax.fill_between(YEAR, ROCE, WACC, where=ROCE <= WACC, facecolor='red')
```

I'm however having an issue at the point where the lines cross as can be seen in the attached image. I suspect I'll have to interpolate the line points. Any idea how one fixes this?

Thanks!

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr7WJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Default, [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) only looks at the given values. But it also has an option to interpolate to find the exact crossing points for the `where` parameter.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ROCE = np.array([-7.0,-14.0,-11.0,8.0,7.0,17.0,10.0,9.0])
WACC = np.array([4.5, 5.1, 4.7, 3.4, 2.9, 3.7, 3.6, 3.9])
YEAR = np.array([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(YEAR, ROCE, color = 'blue')
ax.plot(YEAR, WACC, color = 'black')
ax.fill_between(YEAR, ROCE, WACC, where=ROCE >= WACC, interpolate=True, facecolor='green')
ax.fill_between(YEAR, ROCE, WACC, where=ROCE <= WACC, interpolate=True, facecolor='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]